# How to tell if a file is being returned in an HTTP response

Tags: rest, http, curl

Let's say I am requesting a url such as:

https://filesamples.com/samples/code/json/sample2.json

Just looking at the url it's not possible to determine if the response is supposed to be a stand-alone file or not (chances are it's a JSON API response, but let's pretend we don't know that for sure). What is the best way to determine whether the item is a 'file' or not? Some options include:

- Whether `Content-Disposition` has the word `attachment;` in it.
- By the filetype (though it's not necessary that a url has an extension in it, for example, the url https://myfile/excelfile could be a public Excel file).

Comment: If the Content-Type header is multipart, that indicates a file is being returned.

Comment: @TylerLiu also, are you sure that indicates a file is returned? https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html Seems to be used a lot in emails and such...

Comment: Seems like I oversimplified it, apparently multipart is more general and applies to any request that contains multiple types of data. From the Swagger docs, "File uploads typically use the multipart/form-data media type" https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/

Comment: @TylerLiu right but that's for a request not a response. I'm looking for the response from a url

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm not sure then. Hopefully someone else can pitch in.